# Code writing to SQLite is slow

Tags: android, android-sqlite

The code below takes data from an ArrayList and writes it to the SQLite database on the device.It runs fairly slow, with an ArrayList size of about 800, it takes about 1.5 minutes.Do you see anything that could make it run faster?

```
Iterator<PermitData> iterator = permitDataArrayList.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    PermitData permitData = (PermitData) iterator.next();

    HashMap<String, String> queryValues = new HashMap<String, String>();

    queryValues.put(PermitDataContract.PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_ID, Integer.toString(permitData.Id));
    queryValues.put(PermitDataContract.PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_TYPE, permitData.Type);
    queryValues.put(PermitDataContract.PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_NAME, permitData.Name);
    queryValues.put(PermitDataContract.PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD1, permitData.Field1);
    queryValues.put(PermitDataContract.PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD2, permitData.Field2);
    queryValues.put(PermitDataContract.PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD3, permitData.Field3);
    queryValues.put(PermitDataContract.PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD4, permitData.Field4);
    queryValues.put(PermitDataContract.PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD5, permitData.Field5);
    queryValues.put(PermitDataContract.PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD6, permitData.Field6);
    queryValues.put(PermitDataContract.PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD7, permitData.Field7);
    queryValues.put(PermitDataContract.PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD8, permitData.Field8);
    queryValues.put(PermitDataContract.PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD9, permitData.Field9);
    queryValues.put(PermitDataContract.PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD10, permitData.Field10);
    queryValues.put(PermitDataContract.PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD11, permitData.Field11);
    queryValues.put(PermitDataContract.PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD12, permitData.Field12);
    queryValues.put(PermitDataContract.PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD13, permitData.Field13);
    queryValues.put(PermitDataContract.PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD14, permitData.Field14);
    queryValues.put(PermitDataContract.PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD15, permitData.Field15);
    queryValues.put(PermitDataContract.PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_TO_DATE, permitData.ToDate);
    queryValues.put(PermitDataContract.PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FROM_DATE, permitData.FromDate);
    queryValues.put(PermitDataContract.PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD16, permitData.Field16);
    queryValues.put(PermitDataContract.PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD17, permitData.Field17);
    queryValues.put(PermitDataContract.PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_ADDRESS, permitData.Address);
    queryValues.put(PermitDataContract.PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_PHONE, permitData.Phone);
    queryValues.put(PermitDataContract.PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD18, permitData.Field18);
    queryValues.put(PermitDataContract.PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_EMAIL, permitData.Email);
    queryValues.put(PermitDataContract.PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD19, permitData.Field19);
    queryValues.put(PermitDataContract.PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_XCOORD, permitData.XCoord);
    queryValues.put(PermitDataContract.PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_YCOORD, permitData.YCoord);
    queryValues.put(PermitDataContract.PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD20, permitData.Field20);

    try {
        sqLiteManager.insertOrUpdatePermit(PermitDataContract.PermitDataEntry.TABLE_NAME, queryValues);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("StoreData", " Id: " + queryValues.get(PermitDataContract.PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_ID) + " Name: " + queryValues.get(PermitDataContract.PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_NAME));
    }

} // end while
```

SQLiteManager.java

```
public synchronized void insertOrUpdatePermit(String tableName, HashMap<String, String> queryValues) {

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_ID, queryValues.get(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_ID));
    contentValues.put(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_TYPE, queryValues.get(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_TYPE));
    contentValues.put(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_NAME, queryValues.get(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_NAME));
    contentValues.put(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD1, queryValues.get(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD1));
    contentValues.put(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD2, queryValues.get(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD2));
    contentValues.put(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD3, queryValues.get(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD3));
    contentValues.put(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD4, queryValues.get(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD4));
    contentValues.put(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD5, queryValues.get(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD5));
    contentValues.put(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD6, queryValues.get(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD6));
    contentValues.put(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD7, queryValues.get(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD7));
    contentValues.put(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD8, queryValues.get(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD8));
    contentValues.put(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD9, queryValues.get(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD9));
    contentValues.put(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD10, queryValues.get(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD10));
    contentValues.put(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD11, queryValues.get(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD11));
    contentValues.put(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD12, queryValues.get(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD12));
    contentValues.put(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD13, queryValues.get(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD13));
    contentValues.put(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD14, queryValues.get(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD14));
    contentValues.put(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD15, queryValues.get(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD15));
    contentValues.put(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FROM_DATE, queryValues.get(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FROM_DATE));
    contentValues.put(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_TO_DATE, queryValues.get(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_TO_DATE));
    contentValues.put(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD16, queryValues.get(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD16));
    contentValues.put(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD17, queryValues.get(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD17));
    contentValues.put(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_ADDRESS, queryValues.get(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_ADDRESS));
    contentValues.put(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_PHONE, queryValues.get(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_PHONE));
    contentValues.put(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD18, queryValues.get(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD18));
    contentValues.put(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_EMAIL, queryValues.get(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_EMAIL));
    contentValues.put(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD19, queryValues.get(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD19));
    contentValues.put(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_XCOORD, queryValues.get(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_XCOORD));
    contentValues.put(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_YCOORD, queryValues.get(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_YCOORD));
    contentValues.put(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD20, queryValues.get(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_FIELD20));

    String permitId = queryValues.get(PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_ID);
    String columns[] = {PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_ID};
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        cursor = mDatabase.query(tableName, columns, PermitDataEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERMIT_ID + "=?", new String[]{permitId}, null, null, null);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("insertOrUpdatePermit", "exception:cursor: " + tableName + " columns: " + columns);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // if count is 0, then permitId does not exist, so insert
    // if count is 1, then permitId does exist, so update
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    if (count == 0) { // if new row
        mDatabase.insert(tableName, null, contentValues);
    }
    else { // primary key already exists
        mDatabase.update(tableName, contentValues, null, null);
    }

    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: Use the existing `INSERT OR REPLACE` statement if you can. Wrap your 800 operations in a transaction. Eliminate all the excessive copying (putting stuff in a `HashMap`, then putting it in a `ContentValues`). Then use Traceview to determine where else you are spending time.

Comment: I don't see insertOrReplace in the [SQLiteDatabase docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html). Do I misunderstand you?

Comment: That is not the documentation for SQLite. That is the documentation for `SQLiteDatabase`. SQLite itself has its own documentation, for its SQL syntax and so on. The documentation on the `INSERT OR REPLACE` statement [starts here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html). You would execute such a statement using `execSQL()` on your `SQLiteDatabase`.

Comment: So yes, I did misunderstand you. So far, I've found that: changing to INSERT OR REPLACE makes no difference; removing the excessive copying shaves about 20 seconds off.

Comment: "So far, I've found that: changing to INSERT OR REPLACE makes no difference" -- that is surprising. I would have expected that replacing one `query()` and one `insert()`/`update()` call with one `execSQL()` call would have made some impact. The biggest thing is the transaction: doing 800 individual transactions (per your original code) will be very slow. Wrap all that in a single transaction (`beginTransaction()`, `endTransaction()`, `setTransactionSuccessful()`).

Comment: Ok, did the single transaction. The total time is now about 10 seconds. That's *yuge*. Please post that as an answer and I'll check it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the boundaries of a SQLite statement (e.g., `insert(),`update()`,`execSQL()`) is that individual statement. This means that your code is doing 800 transactions. Each transaction involves disk I/O, to update the database and transaction log. Doing lots of little transactions gets slow.

For bulk data operations, it is better to wrap your own transaction around the work. Partly, that will be for speed. Partly, that way the whole bulk data load will succeed or fail as a whole, so if it fails (e.g., foreign key constraint violation), you do not wind up with a mix of succeeded and failed operations.

The pseudo-Java for this is:

```
db.beginTransaction();

try {
  // do real SQL calls here
  db.setTransactionSuccesful();
}
finally {
  db.endTransaction();
}
```

(where `db` is a `SQLiteDatabase`, and `catch` blocks are optional)